# Trying to find a 1949 Russian Paper on Transportation Theory

Tags: reference-request

I am a research student in transportation theory. I have difficulty in obtaining this paper:

L. V. KANTOROVICH and M. K. GAVURIN, "The application of mathematical methods
in problems of freight flow analysis", in V. V. Zvonkov, ed., Collection of Problems
Concerned with Increasing the Effectiveness of Transports, Publication of the Akademii
Nauk SSSR, Moscow-Leningrad, 1949, pp. 110-138. (Russian)

I am wondering if anyone knows how can I can find this specific paper, and if anyone knows how I gain access to Russian journals?

Thank you.

Comment: Zion, your institution's librarian could probably help you here.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently this is the book that contains your paper:
http://www.worldcat.org/title/problemy-povysheniia-effektivnosti-raboty-transporta/oclc/28097589&referer=brief_results

It's also present in Google Books:
http://books.google.com/books?id=Pu1AAAAAIAAJ

I can scan the paper for you if you don't have the book in your local library.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
Could you please scan me the paper? (My school library doesn't have this book) Thank you very much!

Comment: @Zion: I requested the book from our Northern Regional Library Facility in Richmond.  It will take a few days until they deliver it to the Berkeley campus.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Pavlov. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Dmitri, at about the same length of time you can request the NRLF scan in a particular article and either deliver a paper copy to Evans Hall library or post it as a pdf on a certain website while emailing a password for you to download it. I can do that with my alumni library card. If you know the exact pages this is a good method.

Comment: @Will: I have used this type of service before with papers typeset in Latin alphabet,
but I am not sure whether NRLF staff can read Cyrillic.  Anyway, the book was delivered to the math library today's morning and it will take only a few minutes to scan the paper.

Comment: Very good, Dmitri. Plus there is always a chance of something worth copying outside the exact article, perhaps a title page or table of contents. You are a good citizen! The advantage for me was that I did not need to park near campus to pick up books, then again to return the books, I just downloaded a pdf. When you already have an office in Evans... I may not have said, the article I requested was in Russian, but with journal and page numbers completely clear from www.mathnet.ru , the final point being perfect agreement with the UCB online library catalog, I made the request through oskicat 

Answer (score 3):

Here is the scanned book:
http://math.berkeley.edu/~pavlov/scans/transport.pdf
Enjoy.

Please consider putting it on your home page (if you have one) so that other scientists
who need this book in the future could obtain it more easily than you.
[I would place it on my home page, but unfortunately its contents has little to do with my own research.]

> how I gain access to Russian journals?

http://www.mathnet.ru/ is the Russian analog of MathSciNet,
which also contains online versions of many (if not all) Russian math journals.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I will put it up on my homepage.